# microsoft_graph Ruby on Rails SDk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure-active-directory, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft_graph API on the Ruby on Rails project but get some error `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/microsoft_graph-0.22.1/lib/communications/call_records/microsoft_graph_call_records_get_direct_routing_calls_with_from_date_time_with_to_date_time/get_direct_routing_calls_with_from_date_time_with_to_date_time_response.rb` when I try to install the gem bundle `gem "microsoft_graph"`. I genuinely think it isn't supported on Ruby on Rails as it's been committed on Microsoft documentation amongst other languages. I would love to know if anyone has used it or can point me to a documentation

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs on this SDK today: `Note: the Microsoft Graph Ruby SDK is currently in Community Preview. During this period we're expecting breaking changes to happen to the SDK based on community's feedback. Checkout the known limitations.`

That said, I have installed this SDK on a rails app using Ruby 3.0.0 and Latest rails today. - V7.0

There are a couple of issues in the SDK that you can check on [Github issues](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby/issues). As for installation, with latest Ruby you should be able to install the SDK.